Direct Queries and the SYSTEM_USER keyword on Power Bi Server?
So if I start up SQL Server Management Studio and run a query I can use the SYSTEM_USER keyword to match a user to a personal id. (This works)
If I use Power Bi Desktop I can run a direct query to get that information and use that keyword as a basis for limiting information that user can see. (This works)
If I publish the report to Power Bi Server and access it via a browser will the SYSTEM_USER be the person accessing the report via the webpage or will it return the information for the server?
I'd test this myself but Power Bi Server is still being setup.

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].
